# Describe two non-homeomorphic connected irregular covering spaces of $S^1\vee S^1$

Tags: algebraic-topology

I am having trouble with the following qual problem.  If someone could help me get started it would be great.

Describe two non-homeomorphic connected irregular covering spaces of $S^1\vee S^1$, each of degree 3.  Explain why your examples are irregular covers, and also why they cannot be homeomorphic.

Comment: What general facts do you know about covering spaces, and which seem relevant here?